# Progressive matrix - 4x4 grid with triangles and crosses

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

My sister sent me this pattern sequence. Please excuse the bad image quality.

[image]

[Source](https://www.oeffentlicherdienst.gv.at/moderner_arbeitgeber/start_im_bundesdienst/selbsttest.html)

Answer (score 6):

I think it must be

> [image]

because

> Rule for plus signs: Every plus sign must be connected with another plus sign in the neighboring cell.
>  Rule for triangles: Last cell of each row contains the triangles that are present in all three prior cells.
>
>  The only option this works with is the mentioned one

Comment: It could also be the top left because none to the triangles in each tile share the same arrangement with any of the adjacent tiles.

Comment: It must be correct.  It is the only choice that has a placement of plusses shared with 2 other choices and the placement of triangles shared with 2 other choices.  The intent was to make it less easy to solve with only half the solution.

Answer (score -1):

The connection is between the crosses which are closest to the sides and to vertices.

On the first row 5 crosses are close to the sides and 1 cross to the vertex.

On the second row 5 crosses are close to the vertices and 1 close to the side.

On the third row 3 crosses are close to the sides and 3 crosses close to the vertices.

On the fourth row 1 cross is close to the side and 2 crosses close to the vertices.

If we add to the empty space the card on the bottom right, then we have 2 crosses close to the sides of the triangle. So my answer is the bottom, right card.